# ng-change is not getting called when drop-down value remains the same

Tags: angularjs

In select tag, `ng-change` and `ng-options` are used. So in the drop-down when i change the value, `ng-change` is getting called. if the drop-down value remains the same, it is not getting called. but I want it to happen. 
sample code is below:

```
<select class="report-select-padding selectdwn" name="additem" ng-change="addFilter(filterItem)" style="background: #989FA9; color:#000;"
    ng-model="filterItem" ng-options="column as column.columnName for column in columns">
    <option style="display:none" style="background: #ffffff;" value="">Add Item</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-change` need a change to trigger the function. you can use `ng-click` instead  to call function for every click.

Comment: No. Due to some limitations, I am not using ng-click.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JgvNTTJWAq2hSkzky6nu?p=preview. Refer this plunker. When you select 1 for the first time, it is printing in console. But if you select it again meaning 2nd time, It is not printing. Now change it to 2, and again to 1. it will print. hope you get my problem.

Comment: That is the default behavior, ng-model value need a change to trigger ng-change function.Since you are selecting same item again,change is not happening there

Comment: Agreed. In the function i.e. ng-change, if i empty ng-model, it should work. Right? If you refer my question, In the ng-change;  $scope.addFilter = function (column) {console.log('my ng-model: '+$scope.filterItem);}. it prints as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

ng-change is programmed to work that way. The idea is to trigger the event on change. See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

It will **not** be evaluated:

- if the value returned from the $parsers transformation pipeline **has not changed**
- if the input has continued to be invalid since the model will stay null
- if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value